# SlidingMenu - фрагмент не заменяется, а просто накладывается

Tags: android-fragment, android, java, sliding

Изучаю библиотеку SlidingMenu и возник такой вопрос. Когда нажимаю на пункт в меню, фрагмент не заменяется и просто накладывается, что я делаю не так. Вот скриншот 
http://piccy.info/view3/6689524/908fa5456593383f9cd3904e80bc9b2e/

```
private void onMenuItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String selectedItem = lvMenuItems[position];
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.instance, selectedItem.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (position == 0) {
        fragment = new NewFragment();
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
    SlidingMenuCreator.menuToggle();
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <FrameLayout  
          android:id="@+id/activity_main_content_fragment"  
          android:layout_width="match_parent"  
          android:layout_height="match_parent" >     
      </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:text="ActivityMain" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_new.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:background="#408080" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="ActivityNew" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ну, так у тебя фрагмент и добавляется во FrameLayout. А RelativeLayout с текстом лежит выше (z-index).

Answer (score 1):

Зачем проверки на null?

```
String selectedItem = lvMenuItems[position];
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

if (position == 0) {
    fm.popBackStack(); // это должно помочь
    Fragment fragment = new NewFragment();
    ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
SlidingMenuCreator.menuToggle();
```